# Using DynamicProxy to Adapt an Interface to a Different Type

Tags: c#, wcf, remoting, proxy-classes, castle-dynamicproxy

I have a custom generic class that is used call methods on a remote interface.  This class has a single, overloaded method, `Execute` which accepts either an `Action<T>` or `Func<T, TResult>` to call on the remote interface.

```
public class GenericRemoteProxy<T> 
{
    public void Execute(Action<T> action) { 
        // Remoting Magic Goes Here 
    }

    public TResult Execute<TResult>(Func<T, TResult> action) {            
        // Remoting Magic Goes Here                        
    }        
}
```

Using the class is pretty straightforward:

```
var proxy = new GenericRemoteProxy<ICalculatorService>();
var result = proxy.Execute(x => x.Add(1, 2));
```

However, I would like to take this one step further and wrap the `GenericRemoteProxy` with a class which implements the actual service contract interface, so that my client code is only dependent on the actual interface that it cares about.  This would be the exact same behavior as the `ChannelFactory` in WCF.  There does not appear to be a native way to do this in .NET 4.0, so I am trying to use Castle Dynamic Proxy to accomplish it instead.

I am having a little bit of difficulty figuring out exactly which type of DynamicProxy I should be using, and also how exactly to convert the calls from my target interface into `Actions` and `Funcs` that I can then pass to my `GenericRemoteProxy`.

My current approach is to use the `ProxyGenerator` to `CreateInterfaceProxyWithoutTarget` using a custom `IInterceptor` to handle the mapping.

```
var calculatorService = 
    proxyGenerator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithoutTarget<ICalculatorService>(
        new GenericProxyInterceptor<ICalculatorService>(
            new GenericRemoteProxy<ICalculatorService>()));
```

Then, my interceptor looks something like this:

```
public class GenericProxyInterceptor<T> : IInterceptor {

    GenericRemoteProxy<T> _proxy;
    public GenericProxyInterceptor(GenericRemoteProxy<T> proxy) {
        _proxy = proxy;
    }

    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation) {

        var instance = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
        var arguments = invocation.Arguments.Select(x => Expression.Constant(x));

        var methodCall = Expression.Call(instance, invocation.Method, arguments);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda(methodCall, instance);  

        if (invocation.Method.ReturnType == typeof(void)) {
            var action = //Create an Action
           _proxy.Execute(action);       
        } else {
            var action = //Create a Func
           _proxy.Execute(action);
        }        

   }  

}
```

My first question is, is this the correct approach to accomplish what I'm after with Castle Dynamic Proxy?  If not, how should I be mapping calls to an Interface to methods on a completely different Type?  I've read that using Dynamic Proxy incorrectly can lead to excessive memory and CPU use, so I'd like to avoid that if possible.

My second question is, how can I convert my LINQ expression into the correct `Action<T>` or `Func<T, TResult>` that my proxy is expecting?  In debug view, the lambda appears to be correct (it shows as `x => x.Add(1,2)`).  But when I try to pass `lambda.Compile()` into the `Execute` method I am told that the method has some invalid arguments.